# What happens in case of multiple requests to the database at the same time?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am currently developing an application in which there is a part where users vote for an image and a message "You are the Nth voter" is displayed. Suppose, 1000 or even 100 users vote for a particular image in a span of 2-3 seconds. How will I make sure that each of those users is displayed the correct value of N with N being incremented correctly in the database?

I am using MySQL and PHP.

Comment: Your server, when you send the vote up, could return in its response the N value to display.This way, the server is responsible to determine the correct N number, and you also only make a single request, which is efficient.

Comment: @batjko So, how many the requests be, they will be dealt sequentially for sure?

Comment: Yes, and at the time a request is served, the N number will be correct for that moment. It might already be out of date a few milliseconds later, but with 100 users per second or so... that's kinda expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, relational databases implement the ACID properties (read up more about them on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) or in some other source).

These guarantee that transactions do not interfere with each other and that the database remains consistent.  So, if a bunch of users vote around the same time and a bunch of queries query, then each query will be consistent with a view of the data *at the time it is run*.  Of course, the results might change over time.

I should also add this.  The enforcement of ACID properties adds overhead to databases.  Not all databases are 100% ACID compliant all the time, so this also depends on your database setup (and in the case of MySQL on the storage engine).  However, in general, you don't have to worry about things being "incremented correctly" in the database, if the code is properly written.